# Applications of Shuffle Proofs

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, reference-request

Shuffle proofs enable a prover to show that a vector of commitments or encryptions $(c_1, \dots, c_n)$ is permuted into a vector of commitments $(c'_1, \dots, c'_n)$ without revealing the permutation itself. There are plenty of papers dealing with this topic.
I am aware of the two commonly named applications:

1. Voting, where a semi-trusted server opens a permuted list of the votes to hide who voted for who.
2. Mix-Nets, where servers in the network shuffle incoming messages to hide the relationship between sender and receiver

**Soft Question:**
Beyond those two applications, where are shuffle proofs used/needed?
In particular, I'm also interested in applications (including blockchain related applications) that currently may not use shuffle proofs, but would benefit from them if really efficient proofs would exist.

Comment: Coin mixing is a potential application of verifiable shuffles: see https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/341.pdf